# Declaring integers in actionPerformed java

Tags: java, integer

So I'm trying to create this program in Java that's supposed to keep track of how much stock there is. Like if you wanted to cook pancakes, you would click a button that said "pancakes" and 1xmilk, 2xtimes egg would be removed from the stock every time you click the button, the problem is that I have to declare the integers inside the `actionPerformed()`, so every time I click the button the original values reset, does any kind soul have the answer?

```
//1100 Button
            JButton bj1100 = new JButton("1100");
            f.add(bj1100);
            bj1100.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("1100");
                    //1100 head menu

                    MAIN f = new MAIN();
                    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                    //250/1100 HYDR
                            JButton bj250HYDR = new JButton("250/1100 HYDR");
                            f.add(bj250HYDR);
                            bj250HYDR.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

       @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Building a250/110 HYDR");


                                    //Stock
                                    int lOmaxel =10;
                                    int lVals = 10;

                                    //Orderpoint
                                    int bOmaxel =5;
                                    int bVals = 5;

                                    //Amount to make
                                    int tOmaxel =10;
                                    int tVals =10;
                                    lOmaxel--;
                                    lVals--;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems the problem still  persists and that everytime I click the "250/1100" button anew, the stock resupplies. My intention is to make is so that the first time I click the button I will have 9 lOmaxel left, then the second time I press it I will have 8 lOmaxel left and so on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not groking scope and OO concepts.

As you indicated, you need something with soul.  A simple design would require a class which actually tracks the inventory in question, and you create an instance and pass that instance into the UI class.

If you wanted to separate responsibilities, you would delegate all responsibilities for modifying inventory to that other class, so in actionPerformed() you'd call a method on the class tracking the inventory.

Comment: Thank you, That's what I've been trying to do now, so instead of having all the variables listed there, I've made a separate class for orderpoints, stock and amount to make, so that it looks like:

  Orderpoints orderObject = new Orderpoints(10, 10);
                                     orderObject.stock());
                             
                                     lOmaxel--;
                                     lVals--;

but it doesn't seem to register those variables so to speak.